# How to append dataframes to a dataframe in iterrows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have created an empty dataframe via:

```
df_test = pd.DataFrame(columns=temp_column_names)
```

and I want to append data in iterrows to it:

```
def remove_milestones_before_scope(df, audit, milestone, milestonetype):
    df = df[(df['Audit'] == audit) & (df['Milestone'] == milestone) & (df['MilestoneType'] == milestonetype)]
    df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
    count = len(df.index)

if count >= 2:
    for index, item in islice(df.iterrows(), None, count-1):
        if item[3] <= item[7]:
            df.drop(index, inplace=True)
        else:
            print(df)
            df_test.append(df) <- NOT APPENDING
else:
    None
```

Why are my dataframes are not appended to my df_test?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try:

```
df_test = df_test.append(df)
```

Comment: Hi: UnboundLocalError: local variable 'df_test' referenced before assignment

Comment: But I thought you created an empty dataframe before you run the program? This error occurs if the variable "df_test" is not yet created. Just copy the first line of your question in front if the if statement